# Duda sobre la gestion memoria en fibonacci

Tags: fibonacci

estoy desarrollando fibonacci para un proyecto, me peta la memoria y no se mucho sobre su manejo. El resultado por pantalla sale correctamente por eso me confundo. Inicio la variable s con malloc, pero cuando intento hacerlo con str y str2 peta. Lo curioso es que los resultados salen bien por pantalla con un segmentation fault al final ( entiendo que es por la memoria). Utilitzo for para calcular la iterativa i para la recursiva la funcion rfib. Con este codigo me sale el error: inferior 1 (process 8076) exited normally

```
 void rfib(int *fib, int x, int last);
    int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int N,x;
        int *s = NULL; 
        char *str, *str2;

        if(argv[1] == NULL) {
            exit(1);
        }

        N = atoi(argv[1]);

        s = malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
        str = malloc(sizeof(char)*N);
        str2 = malloc(sizeof(char)*N);  

        if (s==NULL) {
            exit(1);
        }

        s[0]=0;
        s[1]=1;

        // Calculate Fibonacci Serie.
        for (x=2;x<N;x++) { 
            s[x] = s[x-2] + s[x-1];  
        }
        // Print Fibonacci Serie.
        str2 = "Iterative Fibonacci Calculation";
        for (x=0;x<N;x++) {
            sprintf(str,"%s %d: %d\n",str2, x, s[x]);
            write(1,str,strlen(str));
        }

        rfib(s,0,N);

        //Print Fibonacci Serie.
        str2 = "Recursive Fibonacci calculation";
        for (x=0;x<N;x++) {
            sprintf(str,"%s %d: %d\n", str2, x, s[x]);  
            write(1,str,strlen(str));
        }

        str2 = NULL;
        str = NULL;
        s = NULL;
        free(str2);
        free(str);
        free(s);    
        exit(0);
    }


    void rfib(int *fib, int x, int last) {
        if (x == 0) {
            fib[0] = 0;
        } else if (x == 1) {
            fib[1] = 1;
        } else if (x > 1) {
            fib[x] = fib[x-1] + fib[x-2];
        }

        if (x != last) {
            rfib(fib,x + 1,last);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

El error viene dado que estas accediendo a la posición de memoria N, realmente la númeración viene dada desde 0 hasta N, siendo N no incluido y cómo ultimo valor N-1, prueba a poner en los bucle `for(x = 0;x < N;x++)`

Comment: Si lo cambie pero sige sin funcionar sale: Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted 0xb7fdd424 in__kernel_vsyscall ()